# When $\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{1}{|B_r(\bar x)|}\int_0^a\int_{B_r(\bar x)} u(y,x) dx dy = 0$ implies $u(y,\bar x)=0$ for a.e. $y \in [0,a]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a nonnegative $L^\infty([0,a], L^1(\mathbb{R}^N))$ function. Fix any $\bar x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ where $f$ is defined. If
$$\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{1}{|B_r(\bar x)|}\int_0^a\int_{B_r(\bar x)} f(y,x) dx dy = 0,$$
does this imply $$f(y,\bar x)=0$$ for a.e. $y \in [0,a]$?

Comment: Idea: Suppose not. Then, use Fubini and the Lebesgue Density theorem to get a contradiction.

Comment: what does $L^\infty([0,a], L^1(\mathbb{R}^N))$  mean? Also, did $f$ turn into $u?$

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for the correction. It means that $\sup_{y \in [0,a]} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |f| dx < \infty$

Answer (score 1):

No. Simply let $f(y, \overline{x}) = 1$ for all $y$, and $f(y, x) = 0$ for all $x, y$ where $x \neq \overline{x}$.

Comment: Thank you. Then what is the minimal assumption that makes the statement true?

Comment: @Dal not sure about minimal, but continuity in x for instance would make it true. Even weaker conditions include upper/lower continuity.